# Vector subscript out of range error, C++

Tags: c++, file, vector

When I try to run this program I get an error that halts the program and says, "Vector subscript out of range"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//(int argc, char* argv[]
int main()
{
    fstream bookread("test.txt");
    vector<string> words;

    bookread.open("test.txt");
    if(bookread.is_open()){
        cout << "opening textfile";
        while(bookread.good()){
            string input;
            //getline(bookread, input);
            bookread>>input;
            //string cleanedWord=preprocess(input);         
            //char first=cleanedWord[0];
            //if(first<=*/
            //cout << "getting words";
            //getWords(words, input);
        }
    }
    cout << "all done";

    words[0];

getchar();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43108052/7276612[Doesn't seem to work all the time. Where am I going wrong?][1]

Answer (score 8):

You never insert anything into the words `vector`, so the line `words[0];` is illegal, because it accesses the first element of it, which does not exist.

Comment: I added words.push_back(input) in the while loop, and I still get the error

Comment: Check with a debugger attached if this line is actually reached by the program. I don't think so.

Comment: It says the error is line 779? But the program is clearly not that long

Comment: That's the line in the vector header which causes the debug assertion. You need to set a breakpoint at `words.push_back` and check if it is reached. If not there is something wrong with your logic.

Comment: I don't see anything here about breakpoints:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/
what exactly is a breakpoint and how do i add it?

Comment: Take a look at the call stack to determine the source of the error (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you're pushing anything on to the vector. If the vector is empty, subscript 0 would be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your program never gets round to adding anything to the vector, usually done with `push_back()`, so at run-time `words[0]` produces your `subscript out of range` error.

You should check the size of the vector before accessing it.

Try this:

```
for(vector<string>::const_iterator it=words.begin(), end=words.end(); it!=end; ++it){
  cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach the version of the code where you actually push_back strings on the vector. Its not possible to debug the issue unless the code on which reproduce is available for review.