# Creating a vector of structs, expression: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I am **very** new to c++ and currently trying to complete a few little challenges to get up to speed with the simpler aspects.

I'm trying to create an array (found info to suggest vectors are the same and better) of structs to hold data about 10 people. Each person has an "index" (to identify person1, person2, person3, etc..), a "num" (to store the collected data) and a "rank" (a variable which I intend to use to sort the people using the data collected)

The code doesn't show any errors before compiling, however, when the first piece of data is entered I get the following message:

> "Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>   File: d:\program files\microsoft visual studio\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\vector
>   Line: 1795
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range"

I have tried searching through multiple threads but I can't seem to work out why this problem is occurring.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int index; /*person number*/
    int num; /*number of pancakes eaten*/
    int rank; /*rank used for sorting people*/
};

vector<person> people; /*create a vector (array) of "person"'s*/

void getData()
{
    cout << "You will be asked to enter data from 10 different people" << endl;
    cout << "\n" << "The question is; 'How many pancakes did they eat for breakfast?'" << endl;
    cin.get();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        system("CLS");
        int j;
        cout << "Person " << i << " : ";
        cin >> j;

        person temp;

        people.push_back(temp);

        people[i].index = i;
        people[i].num = j;
        people[i].rank = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    getData(); /*collect data for the people*/

    system("CLS");

    cout << "Data Collected : " << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector subscript out of range error, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161554/vector-subscript-out-of-range-error-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your indexing. The index starts at **0** and not **1**. So what happens is when you push the first element, it is stored at `people[0]`. Then you try to access `people[1]`, since `i = 1`. Hence the subscript is out of range error.

You need to modify the code to be:

```
....
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    system("CLS");
    int j;
    cout << "Person " << i << " : ";
    cin >> j;

    person temp;

    people.push_back(temp);

    people[i].index = i;
    people[i].num = j;
    people[i].rank = i;
}
....
```

Comment: I have never face-palmed so hard in my life, I really should have spotted that.

Sorry for wasting your time on such a simple fix! Clearly I'm too tired!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's no problem at all, we have all been there on a bad day! Hopefully this answer might help some future tired lost soul!

Comment: Also note that if you want to get the last item in the vector, instead of `[i]` you could have use `people.back()` to return a reference to the last item placed in the vector.  That way, no matter how `i` worked, your code would have worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will make that change now!

Comment: In many cases, it is just easier to have `person& last_person = person.back();` and just work with `last_person` instead of specifying the index each time.  Easier to understand, sometimes less typing, no index to deal with, and depending on where it's used, could optimize the code (slightly).